# Swing, Remote Desktop Exception

Tags: java, windows, swing, remote-desktop, indexoutofboundsexception

My Swing application seems to be throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exceptions when I use Windows Remote Desktop to connect to a PC where my application is running. Any idea what might be causing this?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice(Win32GraphicsEnvironment.java:96)
    at sun.awt.windows.WWindowPeer.updateGC(WWindowPeer.java:470)
    at sun.awt.windows.WWindowPeer.displayChanged(WWindowPeer.java:508)
    at sun.awt.windows.WWindowPeer$1.run(WWindowPeer.java:448)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I've seen this twice when remoting into the PC, but I've never seen it in other situations. Because it's all internal to the **Java 7u25 Sun JDK** (look at the *stack trace* below), I'm not even sure how to go about debugging this. Thoughts?

---

**Other information**: The machine has two graphics cards with two monitor ports on each, and Windows is configured to have all four monitors turned on. However, when I remote into the machine, there is obviously only 1 monitor. The monitor with the start menu (and the monitor that contains the app) is identified as monitor #4 by Windows.

`System.getProperties().list(System.out);`:

```
-- listing properties --
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
sun.boot.library.path=D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre...
java.vm.version=23.25-b01
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
path.separator=;
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
user.script=
user.country=US
sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
sun.os.patch.level=Service Pack 1
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir=C:\Code\workspace\client
java.runtime.version=1.7.0_25-b16
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs=D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre...
os.arch=amd64
java.io.tmpdir=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
line.separator=

java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
user.variant=
os.name=Windows 7
sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252
java.library.path=D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin...
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version=51.0
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
os.version=6.1
user.home=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
user.timezone=
java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
file.encoding=Cp1252
java.specification.version=1.7
user.name=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
java.class.path=C:\Code\workspace\client\target\class...
java.vm.specification.version=1.7
sun.arch.data.model=64
java.home=D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre
sun.java.command=com.techemet.client.ClientMain
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
user.language=en
awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.ext.dirs=D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre...
sun.boot.class.path=D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre...
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
file.separator=\
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
sun.desktop=windows
sun.cpu.isalist=amd64
```

Comment: sounds like a jvm bug to me. and have you tried it with VNC?

Comment: @user2511414 No, I'm embarrassed to admit I asked here before trying much.

Comment: Did you try to update to the latest graphics driver on that machine?

Comment: @MicSim I will try that now

Comment: Also see this closed JDK bug (http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4923108) and related bugs to hunt down the problem.

Comment: @MicSim fascinating. Note that your linked bug was closed as a duplicate of [this bug](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4417798), which is supposed to be fixed as of 7u8. Note I am using 7u25.

Answer (score 1):

Sun's document for [bug JDK-4417798](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4417798) (the one you mentioned in your last comment) describes a way to **catch the exception**. Quoting from the document:

```
public class BugHandler {
    public void handle(Throwable throwable) {
        if (e instanceof ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) {
           StackTraceElement[] trace = e.getStackTrace();
            
           if (trace.length > 1 
               && trace[0].getClassName().equals("sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment")
               && trace[0].getMethodName().equals("getDefaultScreenDevice")) {
              your_code_to_handle_exception();               
           }
        } 
    }
}
```

It also suggests setting the `-Dsun.java2d.noddraw` option to `true`. According to this [other document](http://blogs.oracle.com/moazam/entry/j2se_2d_performance_flags), it *disables our use of DirectDraw and Direct3D*. See if that helps.

You could also try to force the application to run on a particular screen, instead of relying on Java's automatic detection of the graphic environment. There is a relevant example using the *GraphicsDevice class* in the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html).

Comment: Good try, but their fix is much more invasive than just this one class. If you scroll a few lines up: "In order to make this work around work you will need the following 4 classes. You will also need to make all JFrames and JDialogs into IFrame or IDialog (all subclasses AND instantiations) and you will also need to register the BugHandler as the default exception handler."

While technically a solution, this is pretty much a last resort disaster fix.

Comment: @durron597 Thanks for the comment. Yeah, actually that's why I included above just one part of that workaround. I knew implementing the whole thing would be overkill. Since you mentioned you wanted to at least be able to catch the exception, I thought that drawing your attention to that part of the code might be useful to you and others. Longshot but have you tried the noddraw option? And what about forcing the app to run on a particular screen? Is that an option? Thanks again.

Comment: Dissabling direct draw seems like a hot suggestion, because Remote Desktop often doesn't work when attempting to use hardware acceleration.